# Redis rate limiting in Lua

Tags: performance, .net, lua, redis

I've implemented a rate limiter for redis in Lua, and I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions that might improve the performance.

An example use:

```
eval '[sha] mykey 1234567 60000 1000 1 10' 0
```

Which translates to:

- Create a hash under key `mykey`
- The current ms since the last epoch is `1234567`
- Limit over a period of 60s
- Each bucket should be 1s
- Increment by 1
- The maximum number of increments for this limiter is 10

Refer to [this](https://chris6f.com/rate-limiting-with-redis) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/redis-db/F0jQzmBJKhg) for alternative implementations.

```
local key = KEYS[1]
local time_in_ms = tonumber(ARGV[1])
local span_ms = tonumber(ARGV[2])
local bucket_ms = tonumber(ARGV[3])
local incrby = tonumber(ARGV[4])
local throttle = tonumber(ARGV[5])

local current_bucket = math.floor((time_in_ms % span_ms) / bucket_ms)
local current_count = incrby

local last_bucket = tonumber(redis.call('HGET', key, 'L'))

local getting = {}
if nil == last_bucket then
    -- this is a new rate limit hash (perhaps the old one expired?)
    redis.call('HINCRBY', key, current_bucket, incrby)
    redis.call('PEXPIRE', key, span_ms)
    redis.call('HSET', key, 'L', current_bucket)
else
    local bucket_count = span_ms / bucket_ms

    -- clear unused buckets
    if last_bucket ~= current_bucket then
        local j = current_bucket
        while j ~= last_bucket do
            redis.call('HDEL', key, j)
            j = ((j - 1) % bucket_count)
        end
    end

    -- generate an array containing all of the possible fields
    local i = 0
    while i < bucket_count do
        local j = i + 1
        getting[j] = i
        i = j
    end

    -- get all of the available values at once
    local all = redis.call('HMGET', key, unpack(getting))
    for k, v in pairs(all) do
        current_count = current_count + (tonumber(v) or 0)
    end

    -- stop here if the throttle value will be surpassed on this request
    if throttle < current_count then
        return throttle
    end

    -- only set the 'current bucket' if we're actually incrementing it's value
    if last_bucket ~= current_bucket then
        redis.call('HSET', key, 'L', current_bucket)
    end

    redis.call('HINCRBY', key, current_bucket, incrby)
    redis.call('PEXPIRE', key, span_ms)
end

return current_count
```

Setup:

- Calling this using [booksleeve](https://code.google.com/p/booksleeve/).
- Running redis in a virtual box Ubuntu 12.04 server vm on the same machine.
- The vm has 8gb mem, access to all cores of my computer.
- My computer uses an i7 950 @ 3.07GHz.

I'm seeing approximately **4.4 async ops per ms**, or **4,400 ops per second**.

### Revision 1

Darn, I actually lied. In my original code I was returning something like `{ current_count, ... }`, but for the purposes of this post I just trimmed it down to return the value itself. (if you noticed, the variable `getting` is never used, and it was one of the items I was returning). I've actually adjusted my code to return only `current_count`, and the performance went way up! (I still think it could be faster). Here's the latest version of my code, which also makes a few other adjustments:

```
local key = KEYS[1]
local time_in_ms = tonumber(ARGV[1])
local span_ms = tonumber(ARGV[2])
local bucket_ms = tonumber(ARGV[3])
local incrby = tonumber(ARGV[4])
local throttle = tonumber(ARGV[5])

local current_bucket = math.floor((time_in_ms % span_ms) / bucket_ms)
local current_count = incrby

local last_bucket = tonumber(redis.call('HGET', key, 'L'))
local not_same = last_bucket ~= current_bucket

if nil ~= last_bucket then
    local bucket_count = span_ms / bucket_ms

    -- clear unused buckets
    if not_same then
        local j = current_bucket
        while j ~= last_bucket do
            redis.call('HDEL', key, j)
            j = ((j - 1) % bucket_count)
        end
    end

    -- generate an array containing all of the possible fields
    local getting = {}
    local bc = bucket_count + 1
    for i = 1, bc, 1 do
        getting[i] = i - 1
    end

    -- get all of the available values at once
    local all = redis.call('HMGET', key, unpack(getting))
    for k, v in pairs(all) do
        current_count = current_count + (tonumber(v) or 0)
    end

    -- stop here if the throttle value will be surpassed on this request
    if throttle < current_count then
        return (current_count - incrby)
    end
end

-- only set the 'current bucket' if we're actually incrementing it's value
if not_same then
    redis.call('HSET', key, 'L', current_bucket)
end

redis.call('HINCRBY', key, current_bucket, incrby)
redis.call('PEXPIRE', key, span_ms)

return current_count
```

With this revision, I'm now seeing approximately **10.2 async ops per ms**, or **10,200 ops per second**. (Even if I just return `{ current_count }` - an array with a single element - I see only approximately *6.0 async ops per ms*!)

Comment: A little bit off-topic but maybe relevant for anyone using redis. Windows now has bash, meaning that [you no longer need sloppy virtual machines](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/DevelopersCanRunBashShellAndUsermodeUbuntuLinuxBinariesOnWindows10.aspx) to install things like redis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I run the code in my laptop. I got 16594.76 requests per second.

Environment:

- Ubuntu 15.10
- Run Redis natively (no VM)
- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2620M CPU @ 2.70GHz
- Mem: 16GB

After some changes I got 17825.31 requests per second.

```
> local all = redis.call('HMGET', key, unpack(getting))
> for k, v in pairs(all) do
>    current_count = current_count + (tonumber(v) or 0)
> end
```

HMGET returns a non-sparse array. It's possible to iterate the array using `ipairs`, which is faster than `pairs`. I removed the explicit conversion to number, as Lua will automatically coerce the types if necessary. After the changes the loop looks like:

```
-- get all of the available values at once
local all = redis.call('HMGET', key, unpack(getting))
for _, v in ipairs(all) do
   current_count = current_count + (v or 0)
end
```

This is the biggest improvement. Then other minor things (which probably don't improve performance):

```
> local bc = bucket_count + 1
> for i = 1, bc, 1 do
>    getting[i] = i - 1
> end
```

1 increment is not necessary as it's the default; `bc` is only used once, can be replaced in the loop.

```
for i = 1, bucket_count + 1 do
   getting[i] = i - 1
end
```

```
> if nil ~= last_bucket then
```

Same as:

```
if last_bucket then
```